# Program compiled on Win7 crashes in XP (Visual C++ 6)

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, registry, windows-xp-sp2

I have a rather large codebase that I've inherited and I'm kind of stuck in the past for the moment. I'm working in Visual C++ 6 in Windows 7 (32-bit), however, I'm targeting an XP machine (Service Pack 2). Corporate doesn't see the ROI of upgrading it to .NET and I've got about as much pull as a Mini Cooper towing a train.

With that said, I did seemingly successfully install VC++6 (without XP compatibility) on my Win7 machine and I can compile and run fine. However, when I try to deploy my release build to my XP machine, it crashes (while it does not crash on Win7). If, however, I build the same code on the XP machine directly, it'll work fine. Running VC++6 on my Win7 machine in XP compatibility mode crashes the IDE upon opening of my workspace.

The only thing I can possibly think of is that the code makes extensive use of ActiveX controls and the registry. I'm not sure if maybe there's some Win7 specific registry modifications that are being made or vice-versa. Then again, I know very little about the registry; I'm definitely much more comfortable working in a Unix environment when coding for pleasure, especially when I code in C/C++.

---

Here's a screenshot of the error I'm getting when it crashes. I'm imaging it's got something to do with ActiveX registration.

[image]

Comment: VC6 includes a remote debugger.  Install that and the debug build of your project on the XP box and remote debug from your Windows 7 PC.

Comment: True. I'll have to be careful to make sure people don't unplug the tool from the network, but it's definitely better than going out to the lab to code. 

But what else would cause this issue?

Comment: You need to investigate the crash of course, however what I'd check first is DEP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596183/migrated-application-crashes-if-dep-is-active + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350977/how-to-make-my-program-dep-compatible

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't ActiveX related at all. This is you bog-standard, 1980's type `assert`. As you would have noticed, had you looked at winocc.cpp line 279.

Comment: Where would I find it; like I said, I'm not a Windows programmer by nature?

Comment: It's part of the MFC library, which your program uses.